# MFC/WinApi: How detect when system language changes in windows 10?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, ime

I'm trying to detect when the system language in windows 10 OS changes, are there any windows message which I can subscribe (DefWindowProc) or another way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: User default language needs logout/login for change to occur. I think *"system language"* is just for Windows welcome screen. It's not clear what you are asking. There is a bunch of things you can mess around it in country/language settings.

Comment: @Timbo: The OP changed the question. It's no longer a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497.aspx). When the system's locale settings change, the `lParam` will be a pointer to a string with a value of `"intl"`.

Comment: This doesn't report changes to input language, that would need `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE`

Comment: For me, lParam is returning 648600 when I change locale instead of "intl"

Comment: @kittu The `lParam` of `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` contains a pointer to a null-terminated string. You need to type-cast `lParam` to access that string. The `lParam` will not *be* `"intl"`, it will *point at* `"intl"` stored elsewhere in memory.

Comment: @kittu The `lParam` of `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` is a "local identifier" ([`LCID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-identifiers)). `648600` (`0x9E598`) as an `LCID` does not represent a standard locale, AFAICS. So I assume you are not refering to `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE`, but rather to `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`, based on your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62403375/).